# First read-in prefab name from a text file getting instantiated to null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `txt` file called **prefabs** that contains the names of my prefabs:

```
prefab1
```

This prefab exists and it works!

Using the following code, I read in the file's content (my prefabs' names):

```
TextAsset foldersdata = (TextAsset)Resources.Load( "prefabs", typeof(TextAsset) );
prefabs = foldersdata.text.Split('\n');
```

I display those names in the editor and then whichever name is selected, my Unity program loads that selected prefab:

```
GUILayout.BeginArea( new Rect( Screen.width/6, Screen.height/6, Screen.width*2/3, Screen.height*2/3 ), displayStyle3 );
GUILayout.Label("Choose Prefab");
selectedPrefab = GUILayout.SelectionGrid( selectedPrefab, prefabs, 1, displayStyle2 );
GUILayout.Label("");

if( GUILayout.Button("Load Prefab") )
{
  prefab = prefabs[ selectedPrefab ];
  sceneBase = Instantiate( Resources.Load<GameObject>( "Prefabs/" + prefab ) ) as GameObject;
  blah blah blah;
}
```

So far, I have only had **1** prefab and this has been working flawlessly.

I have now added, at the top of the txt file, a new prefab:

```
prefab2
prefab1
```

The txt file is being read and displayed correctly in the editor.

At first, I got this well-known error msg about **prefab2**:

```
argumentexception: the thing you want to instantiate is null.
```

But because **both** prefabs exist and everything seems fine, I thought this error message probably doesn't apply to this situation literally!

So, I reversed the order in which the prefabs' names appear in the txt file:

```
prefab1
prefab2
```

Now, I get this error message for **prefab1** which is the first name.

I kept testing this and I realised that whatever prefab happens to be the first one in the txt file, the editor complains that it is null.

I am really confused now. Could anyone see what the problem is here?

Comment: just a guess but I wouldn't split on '\n'.  try Environment.Newline

Comment: If you put another one in the file, does the second one also fail in the same way (ie rather than it being "the first one in the file fails", is it really "everything apart from the last one in the file fails").  @Dom makes a good suggestion too.  If they are separated by a standard windows new line (`\r\n`), that means you're getting `prefab1\r` and `prefab2` - the first one doesn't exist.

Comment: @James: No, the second one is read in and loaded. Only the first one gets "accused" of being null! Basically, I can test both and see that each one is file by leaving them in the txt file "alone" and they are read in perfectly well, but once I have two, the first one seems null, regardless of circumstances...

Comment: @Jtech That's when there's only two.  If there was a _third_ one in the file, does the _second_ one also start failing.  If the newline hunch is correct, I would expect them all to fail apart from whichever one is last.

Comment: @Dom: Do you mean like this: `layouts = foldersdata.text.Split.Environment.NewLine;` It is not recognized...

Comment: @James: Yes, if there is three, the second one fails too. Sorry, that was my mistake. So, basically, all fail except the last one. You are correct. Let me go back to our comment please and try it...

Comment: But in the same script, I have other instances of the same way of coding, for example using `TextAsset foldersdata = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("skyboxes", typeof(TextAsset));` and `skyboxes = foldersdata.text.Split('\n');` I offer 10 skybox choices in the editor that work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I used all your tips, as well as the provided answer, and it now works fine. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Dom in the comments, your problem is likely due to a different `end line` character than the single `'\n'` that you were expecting.

Given that the text file might contain an unknown type of `newline`, you might want to prefer safe over sorry and do it like this:

```
var lineSeparators = new [] { "\n", "\r" };
prefabs = foldersdata.text.Split(lineSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```